# Creating top div adds space at bottom why?

Tags: html, css, scroll, whitespace

I had issue with unwanted white space and now have figured that out, but now I am having issues with browser resizing. How do I keep the two scrolling divs adjust with height and width. I want the div on the left to automatically adjust in height while the div on the right automatically adjusts in height and width whatever the size of the browser is. Thank you for your help.

I am trying to make it easier and display it in JSfiddle but it doesn't seem to display correctly.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="mainContain">
            <div class = "main">
            sdfsdf
            </div>
            <div id="container">
                <div class="topmenu"> 
                    <div class="leftmenu">
                        button    
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightmenu">
                        button    
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="filter">

                </div>

                <div class="left">
                    <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                     <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                     <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                     <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                     <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                     <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                     <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                     <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                     <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                    <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                    <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                    <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                    <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                    <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                    <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                    <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                    <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>

                    </div>



                </div>


                        <div class="containerRight">

                        A

                            <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>

                            <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>

                            <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>

                            <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>

                            <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>

                            <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>

                            <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>

                            <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>

                            <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                            <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                            <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                            <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
                                 <div class="post">
                    A
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>






 <style>

        html, body{
        min-height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;

    }


    #container {
        float:left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 90%;
        width: 300px;
        border:solid #000 1px;
        display: inline-block;



    }

    .left {
      padding:0;
        overflow-y: scroll; 

        overflow-x:hidden;
        height:100%;
        /*-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;*/  

    }

        .containerRight {
        float:left;
    margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 90%;
            width:76%;

        display: inline; 
            border:solid #000 1px;


        overflow: scroll; 
        overflow-x:hidden;




    }

        .main {
         height:50px;
            width: 100%;
            border: solid 1px black;
        }

    .right {

      padding:0;
        overflow: scroll; 
        overflow-x:hidden;
        height:100%;
            width:100%;
        /*-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;*/  

    }

        .post {
            width: 290px;
            height: 100px;
            display: inline-block;


        }

        .topmenu {

         height: 26px;
            width:300px;
            border: solid 1px #000000;

        }

        .leftmenu {

            float:left;
         width: 147px;
            height: 25px;
            border: solid 1px black;
        }

      .rightmenu {

          float:right;
         width: 147px;
            height: 25px;
            border: solid 1px black;
        }

        .filter {
            margin-top 250px;
         width:300px;
            height:30px;
            border: solid 1px black;

        }

        .mainContain {
         height:100%;
            width:100%;

        }

    </style>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here is the fiddle, but when i input the code in fiddle the two divs next to each other don't seem to scroll. In my html editor it looks different from the fiddle. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c977Z/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had modified your code 
the two files are index.html and style.css

### index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <body>
        <div class="mainContain">
            <div class = "main">
            sdfsdf
            </div>
            <div id="container">
                <div class="topmenu"> 
                    <div class="leftmenu">
                        button1    
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightmenu">
                        button2    
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="left">
                    <div class="post">
                    A
                </div>
                 <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                 <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                 <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                 <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                 <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                 <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                 <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                 <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                A
                </div>

                </div>



            </div>


                    <div class="containerRight">

                    A

                        <div class="post">
                A
                </div>

                        <div class="post">
                A
                </div>

                        <div class="post">
                A
                </div>

                        <div class="post">
                A
                </div>

                        <div class="post">
                A
                </div>

                        <div class="post">
                A
                </div>

                        <div class="post">
                A
                </div>

                        <div class="post">
                A
                </div>

                        <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                        <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                        <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                        <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
                             <div class="post">
                A
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

### style.css

```
    html, body{
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}


#container {
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 90%;
    width: 300px;
    border:solid #000 1px;
    display: inline-block;



}

.left {
  padding:0;
    overflow-y: scroll; 

    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:90%;
    /*-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;*/  

}

    .containerRight {
    float:left;
margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 90%;
        width:76%;

    display: inline; 
        border:solid #000 1px;


    overflow: scroll; 
    overflow-x:hidden;




}

    .main {
     height:50px;
        width: 100%;
        border: solid 1px black;
    }

.right {

  padding:0;
    overflow: scroll; 
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:100%;
        width:100%;
    /*-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;*/  

}

    .post {
        width: 290px;
        height: 100px;
        display: inline-block;


    }

    .topmenu {

     height: 10%;
        width:300px;
        border: solid 1px #000000;

    }

    .leftmenu {

        float:left;
     width: 147px;
        height: 25px;
        border: solid 1px black;
    }

  .rightmenu {

      float:right;
     width: 147px;
        height: 25px;
        border: solid 1px black;
    }

    .filter {
        margin-top 250px;
     width:300px;
        height:30px;
        border: solid 1px black;

    }

    .mainContain {
     height:100%;
        width:100%;

    }
```

i think it is your answer if you want to ask anything else then you know what to do ,
and if this is your answer then mark it as answered, so that it no longer reamain in the catagory of unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

i had seen your code , i'd ran it on my browser as it displays under my Mozilla , the fault is not in styling the fault is the placement of your button your button are in the 'id=container' tag which take space from 'id=left' tag hence it is came out due to its data, if you remove :

```
<div class="topmenu"> 
                <div class="leftmenu">
                    button    
                </div>
                <div class="rightmenu">
                    button    
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="filter">

            </div>
```

this section from your code you will see the difference.

Comment: Very helpful thank you, but I do need to add those buttons in that area. Am I supposed to completely seperate that from the container div? I tried to wrap it all in the 300px div because it seemed to be more organized to me.

Comment: If it helps I need it to be exactly like qz.com but with the buttons and extra divs on the left which are not a part of the scroll.